# What is the correct way to have the option tag default value set in IE6?

Tags: html

What is the correct way to have the option tag default value set in IE6?

I've tried doing

```
<option SELECTED>
<option selected='selected'>
<option selected='true'>
```

none of them work in ie6, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/). If HTML, then you need

```
<option value="value1" selected>label1</option>
```

If XHTML (i.e. HTML massaged into XML flavor), then you need

```
<option value="value1" selected="selected">label1</option>
```

If still in vain, then the problem lies somewhere else. You'll need to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) then, for example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2073877</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option value="value1">label1</option>
            <option value="value2" selected>label2</option>
            <option value="value3">label3</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

This shows "label2" as selected option in all browsers, including IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Proper markup is:

```
<option selected="selected" value="1">Some Text</option>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_option.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="someValue" selected="selected">Label</option>
```